# JTable with multiples headers in multiples rows

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

I would to know if is possible to create a table using JTable or something like that, to create this:
[image]

I accept advice and opinions from everyone!

Thank you!

Comment: JTable was designed to have one level of column headers.  If you want multiple levels of column headers, you're going to have to write your own version of JTable with a different TableModel.  This should get you started: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JTable-source.html

Comment: Your other alternative is to define a separate JTable for each task, and put the other header information into JPanels.

Comment: 5157 lines !!! LOLL
I have no ability to do this..

I think, this way is not good, because there will be within the JPanel many JTables..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible all in 1 table, but it's been a while since I've played with JTables, so I could be off. I think to do this you'll need multiple tables, with maybe 1 big "Project Name" JLabel over all of them.

Comment: Thanks to reply, I know how to do something like this, but to construct only **Task Name #1#** __table__